# htaccess rule for redirecting when parameters are present

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.phtml [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index.phtml.+$ /index.php$1 [R,L]
```

I have 2 urls like `https://www.example.com/index.phtml` and `https://www.example.com/index.php` which both point to very different sites. I want to redirect to `index.php` in case there are any parameters found after `index.phtml`.

For example, `https://www.example.com/index.phtml?a=b` should go to `https://www.example.com/index.php?a=b` (second rule). I am trying the above rules but the second one isn't matching (the first rule works fine). Thanks for any help/suggestions

Please ask if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# if there is a query string then redirect
# /index.phtml to /index.php 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.phtml)?$ /index.php [L,NC]

# redirect landing page to /index.phtml
RewriteRule ^$ /index.phtml [R=302,L]
```

Note that `QUERY_STRING` get automatically appended to target URL so `/index.phtml?a=b` will be redirected to `/index.php?a=b`.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your redirect rules.

Comment: with this, the url example.com/index.phtml and example.com are redirecting to example.com/index.php. I would like them to stay on the same page. seems the landing page reditect logic is not working

Comment: ok remove `R=302,` from first rule and retest

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure that your htaccess file and index.php are present in same folder.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For without query string rules.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.phtml/?$ index.php [R=301,NC,L]

##For query string rules.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s.index\.phtml\?([^=]*=\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index\.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: With this, the url https://www.example.com/index.phtml and https://www.example.com/ are redirecting to https://www.example.com/index.php. I would like them to stay on the same page. That's what my first rule was doing

Comment: @pinaki, yes what I got from your question with query string phtml should go to with query string index.php, which 2nd rule is doing. Kindly do let me know what's not working and I could try to help more here 